# How to control the session timeout is 30 sec in the BlazeDS?

Tags: flex3, blazeds

dear friends, I didn't find how to set the session timeout less than 1 min in BlazeDS, web.xml 's timeout at least 1 min , how can I set the time less than 1 min , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the session timeout in the web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

However the value is in minutes.  So I don't think you can go below 1 minute.

Comment: You can set the session timeout in code
e.g.
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1);  // 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

You may try HttpSession's setMaxInactiveInterval(), 
for instance in sessionCreated() method in custom HttpSessionListener (you can specify your listener class in web.xml)